# Not a valid PNG file

Tags: php

I have a code:

```
<?php
    $size = 2000000;
    $types = array('image/png', 'image/jpeg');
    if(isset($_POST['go'])){
    $newName = $id . '.' . $type;
    $directory = 'img/avatars/'; //path to folder with images
    $picture = $directory . basename($newName);

    if (!in_array($_FILES['picture']['type'], $types)) {
        die('Wrong type of file. <a href="../settings.php">Try another</a>');
    } elseif ($_FILES['picture']['size'] > $size) {
        die('File is too big. <a href="../settings.php">Try another</a>');
    } elseif (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $picture)) {       
        echo "Image was downloaded!"; 
    }
    $new_width = 66; //necessary width
    $size = getimagesize($picture); 
    $width = $size[0];
    $height = $size[1];
    if ($type == 'png') {
        $src=ImageCreateFromPng($picture);
    }
    if ($type == 'jpeg' || $type == 'jpg') {
        $src=ImageCreateFromJPEG($picture);
    }
    $coefficient = $width/$new_width;
    $new_height = ceil($height/$coefficient);
    $empty_picture = ImageCreateTrueColor($new_width, $new_height);
    ImageCopyResampled($empty_picture, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
    if ($type == 'png') {
        ImagePNG($empty_picture, $picture, -1);
    }
    if ($type == 'jpeg') {
        ImageJPEG($empty_picture, $picture, -1);
    }
    imagedestroy($src); 
    }
?>
```

It returns an error:

> imagecreatefrompng(): 'img/avatars/6.png' is not a valid PNG file in
>   W:\domains\mysite\settings.php

I checked is it png image:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
echo finfo_file($finfo, $picture); // image/png
finfo_close($finfo);
```

And it returns me: image/png (it is).

So I do not know what is wrong with this code. Would be grateful for any help!

Comment: download the 6.png file and make sure a) it is a valid image and b) it really is a PNG format file not a JPEG or GIF with the wrong file extension.  For that you can open it with a Notepad or Notepad++ and check that it begins with "‰PNG"

Comment: Or (try) opening the file in MSPaint, and then try to "save as", and see if the file format the save dialog box has in it is the expected PNG, or something else.  I wrote a program with a similar issue once... The device sending me the images was naming them all XXX.jpg, but when I actually opened them up in an image browser, it turns out the device was actually saving them as PNGs, and then naming them XXX.jpg instead.

Comment: somewhere you have already assigned the new extension to your file... `$newName = $id . '.' . $type;` please post the rest of your php files...

Comment: that posted isn't full code...

Comment: it's very hard to guess where it's wrong without the rest of code...